# Can native windows be shown in Electron?

Tags: electron, node-modules

I'm working with a customer that wants to migrate an existing native Windows app to Electron in stages. We'd like to be able to embed the native windows inside electron and switch between them and the browser as necessary. I know that Electron includes a module for showing native platform menus. Is it possible to write a native module that can do this for windows as well?

Comment: I definitely want to know the answer of this as well. Did you manage to find a way to do this?

Comment: Not yet. Doesn't appear to be supported AFAICT from reading the docs.

Comment: Maybe it will be possible to reuse dialog window for that purpose somehow?